# iPad apps suddenly non functional

Tags: ipad

I play Criminal Case on my iPad and was asked to join  a criminal case group. I clicked "yes" on the invitation and now I cannot access anything on my iPad.

If I click on *any* App,  it will open up and then immediately shut down.

Any suggestions as to how to fix?

Comment: Reboot your iPad.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense that a virus (if one is on your iPad) would do this. Have you gone through some basic troubleshooting like connecting it to itunes and backing up and then restarting / resetting / restoring

Comment: I edited your question away from the self-diagnosis and prognosis of a "virus infection" and directed to the actual symptoms.  It's more likely something is corrupted and will be fixed by a reboot/restore.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a closer look at the link you used to join the group just to see if it looks normal.

In the meantime I'd restart the iPad and then see if the apps work. If not you may have to backup and restore your iPad. I'm sure that (if necessary) should help clean up that issue. If not, you'll have to go back to factory settings.